# Is it possible to prevent the wrap mode of the active file from being automatically applied to other files?

Tags: emeditor

When I am working with a particular file (`file1.txt`) and click `View > No Wrap`, this mode is automatically applied to another file (`file2.txt`) when I switch to (or open) it, so I need to spend some time and energy to click `View > Wrap by Window` to work with this file. Then when I switch back to `file1.txt`, I need to click `View > No Wrap` again because this file is in the `Wrap by Window` mode; when I switch to `file2.txt`, I need to click `View > Wrap by Window` again, and so on, which is very annoying to me. Is it possible to prevent the wrap mode of the active (focused) file from being automatically applied to all other files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Clear the **Synchronize Wrap Mode** check box in the **View** page of the **Customize** dialog box.